# Disposing of Objects in the User Interface

Tags: c#, user-interface, dispose, idisposable

I am a total n00b at disposing of objects so I apologize -

So I have a class called "Logger" which is where I have a datatable and binding source.  I wanted to have all of my user interface in a different project, so when the user interface sets its DataSource to the GridControl, it uses the following method -

```
public SystemEventLog()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    ConnectionLogGrid.DataSource    = Logger.ConnectionLog.GetBindingSource(this);
    ExceptionLogGrid.DataSource     = Logger.ExceptionLog.GetBindingSource(this);
    SystemLogGrid.DataSource        = Logger.SystemLog.GetBindingSource(this);
}
```

The corresponding method in the Logger class looks like this -

```
private static Control LogControl;
public static BindingSource GetBindingSource(Control LogControl)
{
    if (Logger.ConnectionLog.LogControl == null)
    {
        Logger.ConnectionLog.LogControl = LogControl;

        if (Source == null)
        {
            Source = new BindingSource()
            {
                DataSource = GetTable()
            };
        }
        return Source;
    }
    else
    {
        Logger.SystemLog.AddEntry("Logging", "A second binding source has attempted to bind to the Connection Log.", "Logger.ConnectionLog.GetDataSource");
        return null;
    }
}
```

And this is how stuff elsewhere in the program add an entry to the log...

```
public static void AddEntry(string Message, Log.ConnectionCategory ConnectionCategory)
{
    if (Logger.ConnectionLog.LogControl != null)
    {
        if (Logger.ConnectionLog.LogControl.InvokeRequired)
        {
            Logger.ConnectionLog.LogControl.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
            {
                ThreadWrapper(Message, ConnectionCategory);
            });
        }
        else
        {
            ThreadWrapper(Message, ConnectionCategory);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        ThreadWrapper(Message, ConnectionCategory);
    }
}
```

Whenever I close the program I get an Exception that says I have tried to access a control that has already been disposed - where and how should I dispose of it?  What is the actual object that is causing the error?

Thanks in advanced,
William

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you are using threads...in this case in the exit method you should be shutting down all the threads and wait for them to terminate before exiting the application. I am assuming the threads are trying to access the disposed objects.

also, when dealing with classes that implement IDisposable you should have code like...

using( var sc = new SqlConnection( ) )
{
 ...//use it
}

here is an example from an app I wrote:

```
    private static List<Thread> threads = new List<Thread>();

    public static void Start ( )
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < Environment.ProcessorCount * 2; i++)
        {
            var t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(QueueReader));

            threads.Add(t);

            t.Start();
        }
    }

    public static void Stop ( )
    {
        threads.ForEach(t => { t.Abort(); t.Join(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15)); });
    }
```